# sql server 2008 enable sa user or windows administrator user

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008

sa and windows administraor are disabled in sql server 2008
How can enable users?
I have access administrator to windows

Comment: check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx

Comment: Why do you need to enable the SA account? There is generally no reason to use it, and very good reason not to use it.

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/

Answer (score 0):

Login into machine as Administrator , then login SQL Server via SSMS using `Windows Authentication` then

```
Goto Object Explorer --> Security --> Login --> sa --> (Right Click) Properties
```

here make sure `Status` for login in `Enabled` .

[image]

**Note**

Obviously you also have to make sure that SQL Server Authentication is also enabled.

Comment: i have no access to do this.

Comment: You have no access? at what point does this process fail? What error do you get? Did you try the MSDN link that was posted earlier?